# Selenium side runner cannot download file in headless mode

Tags: selenium-ide

I recorded a side file for download some file from a website via Selenium IDE and played it back with Selenium side runner. it works fine in **non-headless** mode. But once I switched to **headless** mode, the download won't happen anymore. I'm using the following Selenium side runner parameters.

```
selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[--headless,--nogpu,--disable-popup-blocking, --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection, --safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist] browserName=chrome" ddd.side
```

I disabled download protection and other things, but it still cannot work. Any hints???

Comment: We finally figured it out. In headless mode, by default, selenium disabled file download. You must enable it by setting download path for each session. "--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection" param doesn't  work as its name sounds like.

Comment: Could you please post the solution? How did you get it working? I am stuck at the same place.